# Cluster-insight on Google Container Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Hi I am trying to enable [Graph tab](https://github.com/google/cluster-insight) in my Kubernetes UI on GKE.
is there a way to enable it on GKE ?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions on the cluster insight page (which you linked to) explain how to deploy the graph as a service into your cluster and then access its interface using `kubectl proxy` and your web browser.